# Android TabBar - Slides up along with the keyboard opening up

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tabhost, tabbar

Is there a way to not have the tab bar slide up along with the keyboard when a user touches the textbox in a screen?

Right now, in the default implementation, along with the keyboard opening up, the tab bar moves upwards and is visible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: also experiencing this. (solution is to disable scrolling on the scrollview or loose the scrollview). Sorry but for the moment.. it seems this is the only way. Ugly, I know! Hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using fragments with EditText and no scroll view inside them and I still had that problem. A solution for me was to add the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" property to the activity in the manifest. Not sure if it will work for normal activities, but perhaps this is a good place to start:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```